# WHICH TARGET FRAMEWORK IS REQUIRED XAMARIN FORMS 10

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for App1.Android (v9.0) is less than the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms (10.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Application.

Previously I was getting same error with android 8.1 then I changed Target Framework to android 9.
Now it is giving same error for android 9 How to fix it I don't have Target Framework for android 10.

When I am forcefully changing android version to 10 via .csproj file I am getting this error
Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v10.0'. App1.Android

I want to work on C# XAMARIN using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: its a poorly written error message as I thought it was saying Xamarin Forms 10 requires a higher android target framework, but of course Xamarin Forms isn't on the 10th version, so it actually saying that "Xamarin forms requires targeting Android 10 or higher". I am not sure why Visual studio lets you select other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update to VS2019, to target API Level 29 which is Android 10. Visual Studio 2017 only supports up to Android 9, API Level 28.